# CREATE FUNCTION must be the only statement in the batch

Tags: sql-server

Necesito ayuda por favor. Tengo el siguiente código en sql server, pero me salen errores como "incorrect syntax "CREATE FUNCTION" must be the only statement in the batch" y también me sale error en la parte del return

```
create function dbo.ventasxciudad_dada (@ciudad_dada char(3))
returns varchar(MAX)
As
Beg
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hay muchos problemas con tu código. Primero que todo, tienes un `BEGIN` sin su correspondiente `END`. En segundo lugar, estás haciendo un `SELECT` que tiene un `GROUP BY`, con lo cual es factible que entregue como resultado varias filas (y tu función es escalar). En tercer lugar, no estás asignando ese resultado a ninguna variable, y simplemente pasando eso al `RETURN`, lo que también está malo

Comment: En este caso seria una función de agregado?

Comment: Se me olvidó que además estás usando un `INTO` que no funciona de esa forma en SQL Server

Comment: Como podría reemplazar ese "INTO"?

Comment: La verdad es que primero necesitaría entender qué quieres lograr con esta función

Comment: Tengo que imprimir las ventas de una ciudad dada, por medio de una función

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas resolvió tu problema, recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Si tú encontraste tu propia respuesta, escríbela abajo como una respuesta y luego la marcas como aceptada. Así otros sabrán cuál es la solución cuando se encuentren con el mismo problema

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que manipular variables en tu función para poder usarlas en el mensaje de salida. Concatenar será siempre mejor con CONCAT. Y para asignar múltiples variables no se usa INTO en sql server. Este es un ejemplo simplificado:

```
create function dbo.ventasxciudad_dada(@ciudad_dada char(3))
returns varchar(50)
As
Begin
   declare @nombre varchar(50), @valorventas int
   
   Select @nombre = 'nomciudad', @valorventas = 12
   
   return CONCAT(@nombre, '---->', @valorventas)
end;
go
```

Llamando la función

`select dbo.ventasxciudad_dada('abc')`

Saldrá algo como

`nomciudad---->12`

PD. También te faltaba un END para cerrar la definición de la función. GO sólo le dice al cliente que ejecute lo que lleva en el buffer; algo parecido al `/` en oracle.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedó bastante claro

Answer (score 0):

Veo algunos inconvenientes con tu declaración de función:

- Debes declarar las variables que vas a utilizar
- Los nombres de variables **deben** iniciar con el símbolo `@`
- La sintaxis para retornar valores de un select en variables no es la que estás utilizando, sino es `select @variable = campo/valor/etc`
- La correcta indentación no ayuda a las computadoras, pero si a los humanos, a entender el código y su flujo.
- La semántica de las clausulas `on` del `join` y `where` son:

  - `where` sirve para filtrar los resultados de la consulta
  - `on` define la relación que hay entre las tablas en el `join`
    Digo esto, porque filtras en la clausula `on` y, aunque esto produce los resultados correctos, me parece confuso y puede confundir a otras personas.

Integrando estas recomendaciones, tu código luciría algo como esto:

```
create function dbo.ventasxciudad_dada (@ciudad_dada char(3))
returns varchar(MAX)
as
begin
  declare @ciudad varchar(100);
  declare @valor_ventas money;
  select   @ciudad = c.nom_ciudad
         , @valor_ventas = sum(f.val_factura) 
    from CIUDAD c 
         inner join CLIENTE cl ON c.cod_ciudad = cl.cod_ciudad
         inner join FACTURA f ON cl.cod_cliente = f.cod_cliente
   where c.cod_ciudad = @ciudad_dada
   group by c.nom_ciudad

   RETURN(@ciudad + '---->' + cast(@valor_ventas as varchar(30)))
end
go
```

Dicho todo esto, el error que te está dando el SQL Server no tiene que ver con ninguno de los puntos anteriores... y estoy suponiendo aquí, ya que el único código que muestras es el de la creación de la función, que esto es parte de un *script* que tiene más sentencias SQL.

Con SQL Server, se utiliza la sentencia `go` para indicar el final de una sección lógica de un script, que se ejecuta inmediatamente se encuentra la sentencia. Esta sección lógica es a lo que se refiere con un `batch` el error.

Las sentencias `create function` y `create procedure` deben ser las primeras (hasta donde recuerdo, no necesariamente las únicas de un batch. Por tanto, si tienes un script con otras cosas, coloca una línea con la palabra `go` antes de `create function`, así:

```
create table....

alter table...

create index...

go
create function....

go
create procedure...

go
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me fue de gran ayuda